# my wifi dongle with integrated firmware is not working

Tags: wifi

i have recently purchased a victoy wifi adapter. when you plug it into a computer it's supposed to automatically install firmware and start working. however, much to my dismay, this doesnt work on the rpi.

i believe this is because the firmware is an executable file which is supposed to be run by a batch file on the dongle. this works fine on windows but not on a debian os. i have manually installed the firmware for the RTL8821CU chipset it has but it still doesnt work. i believe this is due to the fact it's stuck in the cd drive phase where it tries and fails to install it's onboard firmware.

Can someone tell me how i can manually push it past this step or alternatively how else i can get it to work ?

Comment: Unlike Windows, Linux does NOT run code on random devices which are inserted, and never will. If you have purchased something which claims to do this return it.

Comment: I would not try to extract the Linux drives from the CD (unless you are happy with modding them for the different kernel versions) but look to GITHUB for such things as https://github.com/morrownr/8821cu and see if they support the Pi.

Comment: i used apt-get to install the realtek firmware for the 8821cu chipset. i am aware linux won't run that executable and i want to get around it